# ROW to COLUMN transpose column names

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table `T1` as:

[image]

I need to transpose the table as:

[image]

user need to change the column to row value

I tried it using below statement

```
select name, id, 'jan' as month, jan as value                                         
union 
select name, id, 'feb' as month, feb as value
union 
select name, id, 'mar' as month, mar as value
union
select name, id, 'apr' as month, apr as value
union
select name, id, 'may' as month, may as value
```

But will this work in dicing each record in 12 records?

Is there any better way to do it?

Comment: You should have stored the data like that from the beginning. (But I suppose you already know that.) You can do `UNION ALL` instead here, will perhaps execute slightly faster.

Comment: This was an interview ques, to transpose the row to column from column name for each record in 12 records.
can u please the images for t1 and t2

Comment: Sample data as text is always better that images.

Comment: I tried to do that but data is coming in a single line

Comment: No `year` column involved?

Comment: no just these 4 columns

Answer (score 2):

Unpivot is what you are looking for. I have no way of testing the result right now but the solution should look like the following:

```
select * from test_table
unpivot 
(
  value for month in (jan, feb, mar, apr, may, jun, jul, aug, sep, oct, nov, dec)
) order by name, id
```